# Running npm prepublish on an entire project

Tags: npm, typescript

I have a weird set of "local" npm modules that use TypeScript and depend on each other similar to:

```
A -> B, C
B -> C
C -> D
```

I need to run `npm install` and get all of my TypeScript compiled *in order* or it won't be able to find things properly. I'm under the impression I should use `prepublish` scripts to handle the TypeScript compile but it doesn't seem to cascade the `prepublish` request for local dependencies.

How am I supposed to set up a bunch of local modules with `prepublish` scripts such that they all get resolved appropriately when running `npm install`?

---

Another way to word what I am asking: How do I maintain multiple, local node modules and modify them at the same time? The modules have varying dependencies on each other and it is extremely inconvenient to modify them in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I needed. After updating to npm 3.3.9 and TypeScript 1.6, I was able to use a `postinstall` script to build things on the fly. The prototype lives here: https://github.com/MrHen/TypeScriptNpm

But the important pieces are:

```
// In the module's package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "gulp npmbuild",
  "postinstall": "npm run build"
},
```

And:

```
// In the server's package.json
"dependencies": {
  "hen-doodad": "file:../modules/hen-doodad",
  "hen-widget": "file:../modules/hen-widget"
}
```

And:

```
// In the gulpfile
gulp.task('npmbuild', function() {
  gulp_util.log('Detecting appropriate starting directory...', process.env.INIT_CWD);

  var out = process.env.INIT_CWD + '/app';
  var build = [process.env.INIT_CWD + '/**/*.ts', 'typings/tsd.d.ts', '!' + process.env.INIT_CWD + '/node_modules/**/*'];
  var typings = 'typings/tsd.d.ts';

 // ... do typescript build using above paths
```

Feels like a bit of a hack but this worked more consistently than `prepublish`. To run the whole thing, do an `npm install` inside of the server folder.

The gulp task is optional. Presumably you could use `tsc` directly.

---

It should be noted that this is most certainly *not* how you should be packaging up npm modules. The reason I had to do this involved details from a pre-existing build system.

Pitfalls from doing it this way:

- Does not fit the standard publishing patterns used by npm.
- The built files only ever live inside of the server's node_modules which can be awkward depending on what else you do with them.
- Running npm install twice will *not* grab latest changes. You need to either remove the installed modules or update the version number on the module.
- Each module gets its own TypeScript build instead of building en masse. If you can just build everything all at once you should do that instead.
- Requires TypeScript 1.6 or greater due to how they auto-detect typings files included inside of node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeScript compile but it doesn't seem to cascade the prepublish request for local dependencies.

Indeed prepublish only runs install for dependencies. Your dependencies should already be built (with prepublish) before putting them on NPM and installing them.

Comment: We don't publish to NPM. All of this lives in our code base and is built/installed locally.

Comment: Write a bash script :-/. This is not the way `npm prepublish` or any `npm script` is designed to run. NPM assumes `npm install` should do anything that needs to be done for anything inside `node_modules` before your code is touched

Comment: A simple compile script isn't enough. I need them to compile "in order" so the TypeScript requires/typings fall into place.

Comment: I mean, I get that this isn't really "npm" proper. I am trying to figure out what the cleanest hack is to get around our weird/improper module setup. :P

Comment: After digging quite a bit, I found this set of examples: https://github.com/Nemo157/typescript_w_node_modules_example. What I am looking for is a way to run the Quick Start section in one command. We have dozens of these local modules and I don't want to manually order the build script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using TypeScript 1.6+ which support node module resolution. As you are trying to keep all modules synced, I guess your project is just starting.

I think symlinks would do the job, but if you have more concerns, please let me know.

More specifically, you may either create symlinks manually or take the advantages of `npm link`.

```
cd /path-of-a-module
npm link # this will create a link as global module
cd /path-of-your-app
npm link your-module-name
```

Then you may just maintain these modules happily.

As for dependencies configuration in your `package.json` file, it could be a git repository. But you could probably left the compiled *.js and *.d.ts files there and everything would just work.

Comment: This seems impractical to maintain across various dev environments. Is there a better way to create a link? Something like `npm link pathA pathB`?

Comment: I think you might want to write a script for that, which could be fairly easy. You don't have to use `npm` to create symlinks anyway.